# Gap between search bar and table contents in Bootstrap Datatable?

Tags: bootstrap-4, datatable, datatables

I am getting a huge gap between search bar and table content in bootstrap datatable. Please help me with the solution to remove the unwanted gap.[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid pageStandard">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "IndexDownloader")">Index Downloader</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">Downloads</li>
        </ol>
    </nav>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <table class="table table-bordered" id="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Type</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach(var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.displayName</td>
                        <td>@item.fileType</td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please provide that example, that shows problem

Comment: Can you please explicitly mention what you want as example. Because I have provided the html and view in browser. I am using bootstrap 4 datatable

Comment: Brother your example not shows your problem, so how can we knows exact problem, so please provide example that shows your example. You can use codepen, jsfiddle or SO snippet